# Accessing multiple css property

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this method appropriate for accessing multiple css method?

```
<script>
$("div").click(function () {
  var html = ["The clicked div has the following styles:"];

  var styleProps = $(this).css( ["width", "height", "color", "background-color"] );
```

This is what jquery API is doing.Is above method for accessing multiple property appropriate?Or is that the way?

```
  $.each( styleProps, function( prop, value ) {
    html.push( prop + ": " + value );
  });

 $( "#result" ).html( html.join( "<br>" ) );
```

});

Comment: Well... have a look at the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css1): *"As of jQuery 1.9, passing an array of style properties to .css() will result in an object of property-value pairs."*

Comment: @FelixKling OMG what happed to my eyes and brain.Anyway thank u

Comment: @FelixKling, if you noticed, the code is from that exact page, I think  he's asking about the example.

Comment: @gdoron ofcourse it is from jquery API ,i already said in the post itself

Comment: @Maizere, maybe... it's not best worded.

Comment: @FelixKling will the returned value be in array?

Comment: @gdoron: I noticed after your post ;)

Comment: @Maizere: As the documentation says, the return value will be *"an object of property-value pairs."*. But... if you got the example from the documentation anyways, why are you asking why this way is appropriate? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Maizere, no, the return value is an **object**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You copied the code from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/), mentioning it could help, anyway they show you they pulled all the data with:

```
var styleProps = $(this).css( ["width", "height", "color", "background-color"] );
```

Now they manipulate the data with:

```
 $.each( styleProps, function( prop, value ) {
    html.push( prop + ": " + value );
  });
```

Finally they output the result with a `<br>` between  each name-value pair:

```
$( "#result" ).html( html.join( "<br>" ) );
```